# Outlet w/ground wired to neutral

Tags: wiring

Upon replacing some outlets in my home I came across 3 instances where the neutral wires not connected to the outlet but were wired together. The ground wire was wired to the neutral side of the outlet. The hot wires were wired to outlet correctly.
My question would be: would there be any legitimate reason for these outlets to wired this way?

Comment: It's amazing more people don't die from stuff like this.

Answer (score 4):

There is no legitimate reason for a ground wire to be connected to the neutral side of an outlet.  I've seen cases where the neutral wire was damaged/cut somewhere in the wall and the ground was used as a neutral but that isn't legal and is also dangerous.
You need to do some investigating and correct this. Get a good volt/continuity meter and don't rely on those contactless wonder sticks.

Comment: I have seen this where folks did not understand backstab failures, trying to fix a failed branch.